# Context menu on Button long click?

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener, android-contextmenu

How can I make my app to show Context menu on Long item Click?
I have written this code and it's working.
How can I make it so it shows when I click on some button?

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:textColor="#04B404" />
```

Code:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);


@Override 
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuinfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuinfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Set as");
    menu.add(menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, 0, "Set as Wallpaper");
    menu.add(menu.FIRST+1, Menu.NONE, 0, "Download");
    menu.add(menu.FIRST+2, Menu.NONE, 0, "Info);

}
```

Comment: It is cleaner to use the Contextual Action Bar. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#contextual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {  

  private String[] items;
  private List<String> list;
  private  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  private int position;
  @Override  
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
       fillData();  
       registerForContextMenu(getListView());
  }  
  private void fillData() {  
       items = new String[] {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",   
                        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
       list = new ArrayList<String>();
       Collections.addAll(list, items);
       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,
       R.id.r_text, list);  
       setListAdapter(adapter);            
  }  

  @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater m = getMenuInflater();
    m.inflate(R.menu.our_context_menu, menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.delete_item:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            position = (int) info.id;
            list.remove(position);
            this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
  }
  return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**Activity.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<TextView   
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
      android:textIsSelectable="true"  
      android:id="@+id/r_text"   
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
      android:padding="10dip"  
      android:textColor="#ffffff"  
      android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

Now create a `menu` folder in `res` and put this file in it.

**Context Menu:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
      android:id="@+id/delete_item"
      android:title="@string/delete_string"/>    
</menu>
```

Comment: impressive answer. with more clarity

Comment: that's what i m talk in about. +1 up

Answer (score 1):

You can use registerForContextMenu(View v) method which takes the View on which you want to register you ContextMenu.

So if your Button is called myButton,

```
 registerForContextMenu(myButton);
```

So if you wish to have it on long click just add onLongClickListener and register your button using the above.

Heres an [example.](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/context-menu-in-android-with-example.html#.Uw86eZie5OU)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#04B404" />
```

Now take one button and this all which u did wd text view just do same and on click of that button just do this like

```
Button dialogButtonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonCancel);

                    dialogButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                              


                        }
                    });
```

Comment: dude have u take text view and all ids which u earlier take write all your previous code then add this button dude

Comment: i think u didnt take text view id before u write button code

Answer (score 0):

XML Code

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
```

Java Code

```
btnFb.setOnClickListener(FbListenser);
private OnClickListener FbListenser = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity.getApplicationContext(), v);
                        List<String> lstFb = new List<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < lstFb.size(); i++) {
                                popupMenu.getMenu().add(lstFb.get(i));
                        }
                        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new                         PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                    String Value = item.toString();
                         }
                });

        popupMenu.show();
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

call `registerForContextMenu(tv);` and pass it the view you want to attach the context menu to.

Comment: I tried with your code, doesn't show context menu at all.